# Where can I find a stand-alone coffee wand for home use?

Tags: equipment, steamed-milk

I'm looking for a stand alone steam wand like the [Dualit Cino](https://www.dualit.com/products/cino) .
Do such machines exist nowadays?

Ps. The Dulit Cino doesn't seem to be available in the US and is a bit expensive for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save money, look to the technology of 60 years ago and seek out a stovetop steamer. Possibly easier to find at a thrift store than online, at least at a bargain.

Then again, you may well find a thrift-store "espresso" machine that you could dedicate to only using the steam wand on, even if you'd never dream of making coffee with it. May also depend on the thrift store, or the week (given that stock varies with what they get.)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what [Ecnerwal](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/3385/1702) wrote, a stovetop steamer is probably best for you.

Check out the [Bellman 50ss stovetop steamer](https://prima-coffee.com/equipment/bellman/50ss) which is available for $89. It is simple to use, with low maintenance and can produce good steaming power which can create decent microfoam. It has a steaming wand with a valve you can turn to release the steam giving you the control over how you would like to steam your milk similar to espresso machines.

You will not be able to find anything that is standalone that works like the steaming wand on an espresso machine that is cheaper than the Dualit Cino unfortunately.